# How to decouple admin and public components into separate modules in Angular if I need an open trigger in public components?

Tags: angular

Assuming my Angular App has 2 `NgModules`: `PublicModule` and `AdminModule`. `PublicModule` contains main layout, header, footer etc. My goal is to have the following:

`AdminModule`:

- `EditSubtitleInModalDialogComponent`

`PublicModule`:

- `HeaderComponent` (which displays title/subtitle)

`AppModule`: `includes: [AdminModule, PublicModule]`

If I'm logged in as admin my `HeaderComponent` knows I'm in admin mode and shall display a small icon next to the subtitle which opens `EditSubtitleInModalDialogComponent`. For example (pseudo code for demonstration):

HeaderComponent template:

```
<span class="edit-icon" (click)="showEditSubtitleDialog = true"></span>
<app-edit-subtitle-in-modal-dialog *ngIf="showEditSubtitleDialog"></app-edit-subtitle-in-modal-dialog>
```

So far so good **as long as both are in the same NgModule** and the selector of `EditSubtitleInModalDialogComponent` can be found.

**But how can i achieve this if** `EditSubtitleInModalDialogComponent` **is in and only in `AdminModule`?** The idea is to have all AdminComponents completely separated so they can be lazy loaded.

PS: I know this would work with routing but that's not what I want to do here. It's important to have the functionality inside a dialog that can be opened from a public component.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. I introduced a new module called "AdminPublicModule" that exports the relevant components. Public-Module imports this module. This way I have a separate module that can be lazy-loaded.